# Browse to a file location and add hyperlink to the recordset

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I found some code that allows me to browse to a file location, select it, and add the file path string to a text box on the form. What I would like to do is add the file path string to a table in my database.

Can someone show me how to do that, please? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim fdg As Object
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strSelectedFile As String

Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(3)
'Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fdg
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    '.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems 'only be 1
                    strSelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
                Next vrtSelectedItem
            Me![txtSelectedFile] = strSelectedFile
         Else 'The user pressed Cancel.
    End If
End With

Set fdg = Nothing
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the code above? The code puts the file path in a textbox, if you had bound the form to the table and the textbox to the column in the table you will be able to get it sorted.

Comment: I left out an important detail in my original question. The file path needed to be added to a continuous subform because each record may have several files that need to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, Paul. I left out an important detail in my original question. The file path needed to be added to a continuous subform because each record may have several files that need to be linked. I finally figured it out. The code I used is posted below:

```
Dim fdg As Object
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strSelectedFile As String

Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(3)
'Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fdg
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems 'only be 1
                    strSelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
                Next vrtSelectedItem
                With Me.Child57
                .Form.[IMR_HYPRLNK].SetFocus
                    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
                Me.Child57.Form.[IMR_HYPRLNK] = strSelectedFile
            End With
        Else 'The user pressed Cancel.
    End If
End With

Set fdg = Nothing
```